# Load obfuscated Java code to Eclipse failed because Windows is case-insensitive

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, reverse-engineering

all. I am cracking a java software, it's a jar package. I want to decompile it and load its source to Eclipse, so I can analyze it. My Environment is Windows.

I used Java Decompiler to get the source zip from the jar package. Because the jar file is obfuscated, the zip file contains many files like a.java, A.java, Km.java, km.java... in the same folder (or package in java). Zip supports case-sensitive, but Windows does not. When I load the zip to a Eclipse project, the "no-matter-case-same" files get replaced (such as A.java is replaced by a.java), because Eclipse works on the Windows file system.

I don't want to change to linux, I hope there's a Windows solution?

Answer (score 0):

First, it is very, very bad to crack software. So, you are a bad guy. 
Second, I'd suggest you to try to run from zip. Configure your project to be dependent on your jar file, store decompiled sources in jar file too and add this jar as a source attachment. This should work.

But better solution is just leave windows ASAP and never return to it.